# Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, report-designer

**I am creating a sub-report which is part of main report.
When I am running sub-report individually it is working fine without any errors,but when I am running using main report it is raising an error as below shown.

Some times sub-report in my main report is working fine,sometimes its not working fine and raising an error as shown below.

Thank's in advance.**

Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      Source text : (($V{poa}*100)/($V{COLUMN_COUNT}*3))>=70 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      Source text : (($V{poa}*100)/($V{COLUMN_COUNT}*3))>=70      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:729)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:388)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:347)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2071)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:761)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:271)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:129)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:903)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:813)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:878)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      Source text : (($V{poa}*100)/($V{COLUMN_COUNT}*3))>=70      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:203)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:589)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:557)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.buildConsolidatedStyle(JRFillElementContainer.java:753)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluateConditionalStyle(JRFillElementContainer.java:719)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluateConditionalStyles(JRFillElementContainer.java:707)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:467)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterNewPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1177)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1042)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportEnd(JRVerticalFiller.java:302)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:136)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:903)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:813)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:627)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRunner.java:205)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)  Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero      at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1669)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.BigDecimalMath.divideImpl(BigDecimalMath.java:66)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.IntegerMath.divideImpl(IntegerMath.java:46)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberDiv$NumberNumber.invoke(NumberNumberDiv.java:320)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)      at COPO_1528867947635_263995.evaluate(calculator_COPO_1528867947635_263995:333)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:190)      ... 16 more  
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...

Comment: Try validating all the place holder before constructing the JRXML

Comment: check for possible 0 or null values.

Comment: Thank's for your response karthik,                                                                           
              Please can I have the clear explanation about validating all the place holder means.                                                                                                      
         The second point as you suggested possible o or null values,if i run the sub report separately it is working fine where I couldn't find any error. The error is raised when i run main report only.

Comment: somewhere in the error log its mentioned that Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Division by zero, so the dynamic values which get replaced at the run time , i.e. in your case $V{COLUMN_COUNT} should be validated.

Comment: I couldn't understand it is working fine when i run only sub report without any errors,but when the sub report is integrated into the the main report its raising an error as shown above.

Comment: Can you please share your JRXML

Comment: please open the link I had  shared where the JRXML code is present in that link. Try to open within the 24 hrs because it get expires after that............ https://codeshare.io/2BPLkL

Comment: The conditional expression                                                   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[(($V{poa}*100)/($V{COLUMN_COUNT}*3))>=70]]></conditionExpression> is the root cause. how is that you are replacing the place holders like $V{poa} and $V{COLUMN_COUNT}

Comment: so now how can i resolve my error.I mean based on what condition should I replace to get solve my bug.

Comment: Just for your understanding just replace all these values with some values and check i.e. 190/2>=70 instead of <[CDATA[(($V{poa}*100)/($V{COLUMN_COUNT}*3))>=70]]> for all the value from po a till z. if this resolves your issue then you need to put a condition like $V{poe}!= 0 then perform your conditional expression

Comment: If you don't mind I will ask you an question,please suggest me according to your perceptions. The above what you have suggested its well and good to rectify my error,I don't understand that why does its raising an error only in main report if I run the above JRXML file independently its working well and good.The error is getting raised only when the above JRXML file when it is integrated into another report like(sub report with in the main report).But not always its raising an error only some times its showing the above error in main report.